# How to get url file size of multiple url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, async-await, filesize

I use npm [url-file-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-file-size) to get file size by Nodejs. I want to get file size of array urls. Such as:

```
let arrayUrls = [
     'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0597/0149/3909/files/image_6b47157f-0e00-442f-b5ba-a06588ea25eb.png?v=1675671630',
     ...
     'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0597/0149/3909/files/kata-rocks-factsheet.pdf?v=1671613390'
     ]
```

This is my function check size:

```
await ufs(url).then(result => {
                console.log('result', result);
            }).catch(console.error);
```

Because `arrayUrls` can be large, and function `ufs` is `async/await`. It takes too much time. How can I improve this problem? How can I get file size by url in FE (Reactjs) before sending data to Backend (NodeJs) to check it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can do this is to actually send requests for all of them at the same time. in order to do that you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). So what you need to do you will create an array of promises and use it as arg. something like this:

```
const getAllUrlsSize = arrayUrls.map((url) => {
return ({
fileUrl: url, 
fileSize: fs(url)
})
);
Promise.all(getAllUrlsSize).then((values) => {
console.log(values);
});
```

When you do this you will basically send a request for each URL at the same time.
I hope this helps you.